# which gives Better Performance? Query or the Talend Component?

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend.
Can you please explain me which is the best method to increase the performance. Is it using query or Talend component and also please explain me the possible reasons as well

Comment: what do you mean by query? Using which component?

Comment: Suppose lets say, Instead of aggregating the data using Aggregation functions in tdbinput component(select sum(sal) from table)  from db or using taggregate component in Talend.

Comment: Doing that on the database side will almost always be faster than using a talend component.

Comment: Just asking you out of curiosity, Can you please let me know the reasons for that?

Comment: Using a query will leverage the database engine, while Talend will use java code that's auto generated. The database engine will always try to optimise the query, and if you have indexes on your columns, it will certainly be better than doing the same thing with java code.

Comment: There might be cases where doing it with a Talend component will be faster, maybe for small volumes of data, but generally the database is faster.